# Are there equations for Parton Distribution Functions?

Tags: particle-physics, partons

Are there actual equations for the Parton Distribution Functions for quarks and gluons? I've been looking high and low for theory-based papers about this and it seems like a wild goose chase at this point. If the answer to that question is no, are there any theoretical results that can be used to compare to experimental results? Hope to hear an answer soon.

Comment: Have you tried the textbooks on QCD like "QCD and Collider Physics" by Ellis, Stirling and Webber. Or perhaps the "The black book of Quantum Chromodynamics" by Campbell, Huston and Krauss.